# YouTube API V3 home feed

Tags: json, youtube-api

Using https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/ , is there a way to get YouTube's home feed?

When you launch YouTube it automatically shows videos of 'Popular on youtube' category. Is there a API call to get this feed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is not a feed in DAta API v3. There could be built in soon. But you can mimic it with using [search](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)

Something like this will give you the most viewed videos.

You can use [Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/) for finer detail.