# following specific topics on youtube data api

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have some phrases and I'd to subscribe/follow to all events on them on Youtube, e.g. for "IKEA" whenever a video is uploaded or a comment is created with IKEA in its title or description my application receives a notification. Something like [twitter streaming api](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview). If there is no such a service any recommendation on other solutions appreciated. If no other option maybe I should crawl youtube.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure, where will you be performing this activity like on PC or Handheld device. If I am to do it, I would do it with PC on powershell with command.

There are 2 cmdlets called Invoke-webrequest & Invoke-RestMethod. I can fetch the data by using any one of them.

Invoke-WebRequest - This sends requests to a web page and parses the response. It returns content with additional information including headers, status, forms, input fields, and other site content such as links. This tool can be used to discover and fill in data/fields need to be filled out on a website. basically, it dumps the Webpage, also known as web-scraping.

Invoke-RestMethod - This sends HTTP requests to a RESTful web service, which results a structured data. This tool can be used to send data to a RESTful API to accomplish tasks like detailed account creation.

Below is an example of invoke Restmethod

```
Invoke-RestMethod -uri “https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&q=IKEA” | 
foreach {[PSCustomObject]@{Title=$_.Title; Author=$_.author.name; Link=$_.content.src}} | Format-List
```

You can find more Information on Gdata API for Youtube here.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am using linux servers and [python client](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/search.py) to search queries on youtube api, so Microsoft is no option. I guess your answer is based on calling a search query and receive the data but I need a way to subscribe to the query and receive the video once it is published on youtube. And last thing is that feeds feature is [no longer available on Data API v3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16651612/3990158).